# How to make sound layers visible on right side of screen in Davinci Resolve

Tags: video, editing, davinci-resolve, software

I have used Davinci in Windows but I'm new on mac. So I would like to learn how to display sound bus, layer visualization bigger. I've tried to show which I meant in attached image.

Thanks.[image]

Answer (score 2):

Well, I have found it. For anyone who struggles like me, you have to click "Mixer" button on top right corner
[image]